# why is array.splice changing the order of my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a jQuery object array that I need to remove the 1st and last item from. I tried using `shift()` and `pop()` but it threw an error because I guess a jQuery object is not the same as an array? I then used `delete` however that doesn't change the length so a loop I have after this gets all kinds of messed up. Finally I found out I should use:

```
$item.splice(0,1) and $item.splice($item.length-1, 1)
```

however the object array that splice(0, 1) returns is no longer in the same order as it was previously. Is there a reason splice would return a different order?

Comment: Please share a working snippet.

Comment: Do you know that `splice()` method returns the _removed item(s)_ in an array, which might be why you think it has _changing the order of my array_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)? It works with a jQuery elements collection:

```
$('div').slice(1, -1);
```

Also, you can use the above statement without changing your original array. It returns the collection, removing the first and last elements.